# Actor-Partner-Interdependence-Model for longitudinal data (L-APIM) analysis for data with different number of intervention and no fixed interval

Tags: panel-data, multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, dyadic-data

A friend recommended Stackexchange since I haven't found a suitable answer.

I am currently trying to prepare my analysis of an Actor-Partner-Interdependence-Model for longitudinal data (L-APIM) with different event occurrences.
I have three different cohorts with distinguishable dyads, all receiving Just-In-Time-Adaptive-Interventions (JITAIs). This means that the number of interventions the dyads receives vary among them and that there is no fixed interval in which they receive the interventions. Furthermore, it is not set who receives the intervention (e.g., Partner A could receive an intervention that concerns themselves or their partner).
After studying many different papers and books, I couldn't decide which model would fit my data the best. I am even unsure whether to use a Multilevel-Model (MLM) or Structural equation modeling (SEM) since I only have a total of 40 dyads (pilot study).

At the moment, I haven't adjusted the data.

Independent variable: Did Partner A or B receive a JITAI (yes/no)

Dependent variable: Minutes of daily physical activity from Partners A and B.

My current research question is: Do the JITAIs affect the dyads' jointly planned physical activity?

Any insight and thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to CV @Elisa! Just to be clear: are you asking which of MLM vs. SEM "would fit my data the best" in terms of being most appropriate for analyzing your data given the peculiarities of your design? (i.e., not in the SEM meaning of the term "fit") And I correct in understanding that each instance of an intervention means that an assessment took place at that point in time? If "yes" on both scores, it sounds like MLM would be the better bet, but this sounds like a fairly complicated design to analyze with only 40 cases (of dyads)...